# e4300 Mouse Click/Paste While Typing

Tags: 11.04, mouse, dell

I have a Dell e4300 that is having some irregular mouse driver issues with a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04 x64.  I have used other versions of Ubuntu without issue.   Windows works fine, so it appears the hardware is working properly.  This leads me to believe a driver issue, however I am in need of some direction.

Keep in mind that all this is with a fresh install.  No Docking Station, Only a USB Microsoft Intellimouse.  These issues occur with/without the mouse connected.

Issue Scenario 1:
When I am typing my password to login to the box, if I place the mouse cursor at a location on the left side of the password window, I can type the password normally until I type to the right of the mouse.  At that point, every keypress moves the cursor to the mouse location, then inputs the key.  If I move the mouse outside of the text box, the focus is removed from the text field after each keypress.  This allows one character to be entered at a time. I can login successfully if the mouse is moved to the very right of the text field.

Issue Scenario 2:
Once logged in, I will often be required to press a key on the keyboard to be able to click on something/anything within Gnome.  The keyboard press does not seem to actually input anything, just allows the mouse to click.

Issue Scenario 3:
When I attempt to highlight a group of text, the OS automatically will copy the text.  When I attempt to type,  the mouse would take the cursor focus (similar to Scenario 1), and also copy that previous text.  If I attempt to type multiple characters, it will paste the information at the mouses location within the text field multiple times.

I have tried:
to Reinstall.
Updated all patches
load various drives through the software

I can get around Linux/Terminal, so I do not consider myself new.  However I am certainly not a pro.

Suggestions?

Comment: As a follow-up, I attempted to re-install 10.04 LTS and during the manual partition setup while booting from the CD, the scenarios of copy/paste/click are occurring.  Quite frustrating...

Comment: I was previously at the latest A22 BIOS.  I did try moving back to A21 without any change in mouse operation (no success).

Comment: Not sure if it works in this format, but... Bump?

Comment: Since this is related to failed hardware, I've voted to close this question as too localized.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an follow-up close this issue, it appears that there was failing hardware - Ubuntu was just more sensitive.  Windows eventually exhibited issues as well, although different.

Although the issue appeared to be with the track pad, ultimately it was the replacement of the keyboard/pointer stick mouse that resolved the issue.  The keyboard does connect into the track pad assembly on this model prior to connecting to the laptops motherboard.

Thanks.